# Volume absorption boosts light levels of scene and messes with shadows

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders, shadows, volumetrics

The first has a volume absorption node that is set to full white and 0 density for the water, it also has a glass BSDF set to white and an IOR of 1.33. The second image is the same, except the volume absorption node has been removed from the water material.
[image: Bad image result]
[image: Good image result]
Here is my node set up:
[image: Node set up]
I have tried recreating this effect in a simple scene with as few objects as possible, but I can't recreate it at all. (Additional information: I was having this same issue with a hair particle system in this scene, but that has since been removed from the scene.)
Why is the volume absorption node messing up my scene?

Comment: Please edit your question to include an image of the nodes of your material for the water.

Comment: @RichSedman I have added a screenshot of my node set up

Answer (score 1):

I raised the max volume light bounces to 64 and that has solved the issue